# How to cast a class in java with a lists index

Tags: java

I created a dropdown with say 5 values. What I want is if you select the 3de value I want to use that index (2) to cast to my  class. See below my small class

```
   public class dropDownConstructor
{
    public String Code = "";

    public  dropDownConstructor(String code)
    {
              Code = code;

    }

}
```

I added values to it as follow

```
          myList = new ArrayList<dropDownConstructor>();
       myList.add(new dropDownConstructor("ABS"));
```

And then I tried to cast it as follow

```
  dropDownConstructor d = (dropDownConstructor)myList;
```

In short I would like to cast  with an index so I can retrieve a specific record. I know how to do this in c# but I am struggling in java.

Comment: You should use `dropDownConstructor d = myList.get(someIndex);`. No need to cast.

Answer (score 3):

This is not at all valid :

```
dropDownConstructor d = (dropDownConstructor)myList;
```

You are trying to cast a list to `dropDownConstructor` which will never happen.

Probably, you mean something like this :

```
dropDownConstructor d = (dropDownConstructor)myList.get(0); //assuming non-empty list.
```

If that is what you want, then you do not need a cast, if you use generic declaration of your list like :

```
List<dropDownConstructor> myList = new ArrayList<dropDownConstructor>();
myList.add(new dropDownConstructor("ABS"));

dropDownConstructor d = myList.get(0);
```

This guaranteed that your `get` will return an object of type `dropDownConstructor`, because whenever you try to add anything to list that is not of type `dropDownConstructor`, it won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

```
dropDownConstructor d = myList.get(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `myList` is a `ArrayList<dropDownConstructor>`, you can't cast it to a `dropDownConstructor`. Its elements are `dropDownConstructor`s.

For example, you can iterate over them :

```
for (dropDownConstructor d : myList) {
    // do something with d
}
```

And you can search if a specific `dropDownConstructor` is in the List :

```
if (myList.contains(someDownConstructor)) {

}
```

To the the `i`'th element, use `myList.get(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Conventions and usage:

```
public class DropDown
{
    public String code = "";

    public  DropDown(String code)
    {
         this.code = code;
    }
}

List<DropDown> myList = new ArrayList<>();
myList.add(new DropDown("ABS"));

DropDown d = myList.get(42);
for (DropDown d : myList) { ... }
```